# How do I include or bundle node_modules in a cordova-electron application?

Tags: cordova, electron, node-modules

Using Cordova-electron: How can I have Cordova - electron bundle all required node_modules into the application (so that a user doesn't need node and it's modules installed)?

Do I need to install electron-packager on top of cordova-electron?
Do I need to run hooks?

And how would I do this, if I need to require some stuff in the `platform_www` (renderer)?

Is there some 'best practices' or a demo-project to see how that works?

Answer (score 0):

Project-level node module bundling support was just introduced in version `1.1.0`.

There is more information on this in the [Cordova Electron Documentation: Bundling Node Modules](https://github.com/apache/cordova-electron/blob/rel/1.1.0/DOCUMENTATION.md#bundling-node-modules).